# What's an accurate/alternative way to represent the idea of a "blueprint"?

Tags: phrasing

This is in a programming context, for some financial software.

An Investment can have a lot of Processes that apply to it (ex: both parties need to sign 'x' set of documents, called 'Subscription' documents, so a process might be the Subscription Process)

Each process consists of a variety of ordered tasks. (ex: Investor Signing, then Sponsor Signing)

So, there's two kinds of data I need to store. Data about the 'Process' and the 'Tasks' in general, that's the same no matter the investment. And then there's data that's specific to each investment.

So, off the bat, I was thinking, I'd have "blueprint" versions of processes/tasks that get linked up with the individual, investment-specific ones.

- *InvestmentProcessBlueprint* (general process info needed by every investment)
- *InvestmentTaskBlueprint* (general task info needed by every investment)
- *InvestmentProcess* (data specific to an investment)
- *InvestmentTask* (data specific to an investment)

So in a sense, the blueprint produces the other task. But...this doesn't feel quite right to me. And that's because it diverges from natural language that, spoken by people who were just introduced to the software, would make sense to them. I'm not sure what other word fits, or how to twist these concepts around.

Comment: Such things are usually called templates.  See for example [Microsoft Word Templates](https://templates.office.com/en-us/templates-for-Word).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Template** - A shaped piece of rigid material used as a pattern for processes such as cutting out, shaping, or drilling.  [ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/template)

See also this [techterms entry](https://techterms.com/definition/template)

Comment: Duh! I totally overlooked this word. That's exactly what they are!! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

"Template" is good.

Depending on how you are organizing things, I might consider

General_Investment_Process pointing to Investment_Tasks that are common to many or all investment processes and

[Specific]_Investment_Process pointing to Investment_Tasks that are necessary to this specific process.

What I like about that arrangement is how easy it is to add new processes.